# path environment variable & unresolved external symbol

Tags: visual-studio-2008, linker-errors

I've been stuck with this unresolved external symbol error for more than a week now. Say, with TBB lib (and PointGrey lib to be mentioned in another post), I cannot link to the libraries (dll or lib I'm not sure!) and it brings this kind of linking error.

[image: this is a configuration guide from Intel about TBB lib]

I'm using VS2008, win7. This guide means that I just need to run the script file, then every project I create will be automatically configed properly (according to (1)). Am I getting it right?

So far, original sample project from Intel run properly without any of my config, I just click run. But with the projects I created from the same sample code, they have linking errors

PS: the script is: tbbvars.bat <\arch>\ <\vs>\

Comment: I mentioned "Path" environment variable because: in VS2008, in tools/option/Projects and Solutions/VC++ Directories, there is an option "Executable files" to add more libraries to projects (here is dll). I want to use this instead of adding to Win32 environment variable "Path". Is this possible??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some libraries are linked as lib files, and the sometimes the project needs to be told of these dependencies. The help you show tells you to go into your Project -> Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies, and add the tbb_debug.lib or tbb.lib (use the _debug version if you build in Debug mode, the other in Release) - They probably have other two versions for x64 builds, so you should do this for each build version.
Then go to the Project -> Properties -> Linker -> Input -> General -> Additional Library Directories and add the library directory they suggest. (again, separate directories for 32/64 bits). 
Of course, also  VC/c++ Properties -> General -> Include Directories, where you will add $(TBBROOT)\include. 
Check the Project Properties for the sample projects that you have from Intel. 
If you run their script, if any dlls get to be included in the executable they will be found by the linker (and/or during execution). What is more important, they create the Env Var TBBROOT, looks like - which is referenced by what you are supposed to add in the properties. If you don't have that variable, you will have to add absolute paths.
 
As for the option in your comment, yes you can tell VS to look for libraries somewhere else instead of adding an extra Env Var (or more paths to the PATH). The only thing to consider is whether some dlls are required for execution - in which case you might want to copy them in the same folder as your exe after the build, and use absolute path in the includes. It is also a little bit less portable...

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll check this next week & give feedbacks. For now, what I do is just copying the sample projects which are already configured & compiled properly and feed in the code I want :). still work anyway!

Comment: Thanks for your very clear answer! especially it hits my question about env var PATH. I've tried to reconfigure the project. Now, no compile/linking error exists. However, there comes run-time error. probably I used wrong lib. I'll give some more try

Comment: @Son: I am glad that I was able to help. Feel free to also mark my answer as useful, if you think it was.